# So many sub-queries in advanced search "Mysql-Laravel"

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, subquery, advanced-search

I'm building an "Ads" Website based on Laravel as an API where it contains a dynamic-advanced search.

Ads can have multiple attributes and the user can have advanced search, but it leads to so many sub-queries if user checked so many attributes to filter by and the query become slow, Any advice about better query than this one.

```
select
 *
from
  `ads`
where
  `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 32
      and `value` in ('odio', 'quos', 'dignissimos', 'dolorem', 'qui')
  )
  and `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 171
      and `value` in ('itaque', 'non', 'dolor', 'laborum')
  )
  and `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 111
      and `value` in ('quia', 'non', 'nam', 'molestias')
  )
  and `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 144
      and `value` in ('delectus', 'nam', 'exercitationem', 'sit')
  )
  and `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 160
      and `value` in ('repellat', 'fugit', 'quaerat', 'vero')
  )
  and `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 176
      and `value` in ('mollitia', 'voluptates', 'maxime', 'culpa')
  )
  and `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      `attribute_id` = 177
      and `value` in ('necessitatibus', 'id')
  )
```

and here's the code for the search, PS. I'm using a mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery instead of using whereHas because its even slower....

```
->when(!empty($search->attrs), function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
            foreach ($search->attrs as $key => $value) {
                if (!is_null($value)) {
                    $query->hasByNonDependentSubquery('adAttributes', function (Builder $q) use ($value, $key, $search) {
                        $q->where('attribute_id', $key)
                            ->when(is_array($value), fn($q) => $q->whereIn('value', $value))
                            ->when(!is_array($value), fn($q) => $q->where('value', $value));
                    });
                }
            }
            return $query;
        });
```

I added Some of the data in my database, I cant share all of it because its dummy seeded data thats around 60k on Fiddle [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f00cc71fff716837906c22d46b0c899][1]

Comment: How slow are you talking?

Comment: @Savlon I'm still not in production I seeded around 10k rows in ad_attributes and 50k ads. the query takes around 30 ms without the sub-queries and it keeps growing as I add more filters and more sub-queries .... the query I posted takes around 0.5 seconds

Comment: Please shrink the question to 2 (not 7) IN's, each with only 2 options.  Then provide data sample data that has some rows you want and some that you don't want.  In particular, provide some rows that nnichols' formulation would mistakenly include.  And let's focus on the SQL (on the assumption that you can work backward to Elequent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be absolutely useless and perform really badly but I vaguely remember using something along these lines when battling an EAV performance issue many years ago. I do not have a suitable test dataset to test this against so I may be making a complete fool of myself by suggesting this.

```sql
select
 *
from
  `ads`
where
  `ads`.`id` in (
    select
      `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    from
      `ad_attributes`
    where
      (`attribute_id` = 32  and `value` in ('odio', 'quos', 'dignissimos', 'dolorem', 'qui')) OR
      (`attribute_id` = 171 and `value` in ('itaque', 'non', 'dolor', 'laborum')) OR
      (`attribute_id` = 111 and `value` in ('quia', 'non', 'nam', 'molestias')) OR
      (`attribute_id` = 144 and `value` in ('delectus', 'nam', 'exercitationem', 'sit')) OR
      (`attribute_id` = 160 and `value` in ('repellat', 'fugit', 'quaerat', 'vero')) OR
      (`attribute_id` = 176 and `value` in ('mollitia', 'voluptates', 'maxime', 'culpa')) OR
      (`attribute_id` = 177 and `value` in ('necessitatibus', 'id'))
    group by `ad_attributes`.`ad_id`
    having count(`attribute_id`) = 7
  )
```

**EDIT**
As stated in my first comment below - `You may need to COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id), depending on whether ads can have multiple rows for the same attribute_id`. As your test dataset does have multiple rows for the same ad_id, attribute_id pair, you need to add `DISTINCT`.

I have added to your original [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0e8f8/7) and your [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6178f3e531d7f5677a9b0b1a76e7e55a). Unfortunately db<>fiddle does not return the execution time for each query.

Based on the tables in both your fiddles, there are currently no indices on these tables. You also have a needless surrogate primary key on your ad_attributes table instead of the natural key on either (ad_id, attribute_id) or (ad_id, attribute_id, value). The second version is required if you allow/need multiple rows of the same attribute_id per ad_id, as it currently the case in your test data. Is this intended or just an error in the way your test data was created?

Of your 776 test rows in ad_attributes, there are 106 sets of (ad_id, attribute_id, attribute_option_id, value) with two or more copies, and the worst has six copies. I would suggest that your test data is not useful as it does not follow the basic rules and constraints that will be needed in your production dataset. Testing queries with totally random data is not particularly useful. Your test data should attempt to model what you are likely to see in production data.

I am not totally confident that I understand the intent of your data structure. What is the thinking behind having attribute_option_id and value columns? What is the thinking behind text and option attributes? Do you really ever need a text attribute? Think about this last one very carefully as it has the potential to have a very significant impact on data quality and performance as your dataset grows.

Comment: thanks for taking time trying to help, the `OR` won't help because the client wants the results to for example has `odio` and has `non` and has `quia` ...etc :(

Comment: You use the `OR`s to retrieve all the potential matches without multiple joins or sub-queries. You then use the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` of the attributes retrieved to see how many attributes meet the requirements, in this case all seven. You may need to `COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id)`, depending on whether ads can have multiple rows for the same attribute_id. It does work but may be even slower than your current sub-queries.

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir - In spite of your Comment, did it get the same results as your original formulation?

Comment: @RickJames No, The query I posted returned 91 rows, the query in the comment returned 2 rows

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir - Sorry, I still don't see it; can you show two of the 91 rows in nnichols' query that show up as (more correctly) one of the 2 rows by your query.

Comment: @RickJames Actually both of ads are not part of 91 ads in the origin query,

I think the reason is that some ads doesn't have all required attributes but their count is 7 for example which make them true too, like an ad has some of the `OR`s but the count after the group is 7 so thats why its returned .

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir If you can make your test dataset available for download somewhere I'd be intrigued to look into the different result sets for our two queries.

Comment: @nnichols I added a fiddle url it contains part of my tables so you can run tests on it, now its not going to be the same 2 rows - 91 rows because I added 334 ads instead of 50k ads

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir I found the problem. As stated in my first comment above - `You may need to COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id), depending on whether ads can have multiple rows for the same attribute_id`. Please read the edited answer.

Comment: I really have no words to thank you enough, the discussion was really helpful, I really appreciate  your time trying to help, The edit was really helpful and the `COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id)` worked as a charm, in production it shouldn't be a problem because it shouldn't have multiple values for the same attribute but the seeded data has this problem that I didn't notice. I'm gonna mark it as resolved now, thank again :)

Comment: I'm glad we got there in the end. How long did the three different queries take to execute against you test data?

Comment: @nnichols one of my tests took around 45 seconds, I dont remember the parameters I passed that time. but now I tested multiple conditions from the website "old code and new code" and I got ~20ms, from the new code instead of 2-3 seconds in some cases from old code. if I can remember the 45s parameters I will test and reply again but I think its not gonna be that bad at the end

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to just join the table and use `where()`?

```php
$query = Ads::select('ads.*')->join('ads_attributes', 'ads.id', 'ads_attributes.ad_id');

if (!empty($search->attrs) {
    foreach ($search->attrs as $k=>$v) {
        $q->orWhere(function (Builder $q) (use $k, $v) {
            $q->where('ads_attributes.id', $k)
                ->when(
                    is_array($v),
                    fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('value', $v),
                    fn ($q) => $q->where('value', $v),
                );
        });
    }
}

return $query;
```

Comment: The where clause becomes
  and (
    `ad_attributes`.`attribute_id` = 111
    and `value` in ('quia', 'non', 'nam', 'molestias')
  )
  and (
    `ad_attributes`.`attribute_id` = 144
    and `value` in ('delectus', 'nam', 'exercitationem', 'sit')
  )
  and (
    `ad_attributes`.`attribute_id` = 160
    and `value` in ('repellat', 'fugit', 'quaerat', 'vero')
  ).... etc
which will always be false !!

Comment: Your original query is all `and` as well. Change the outer `where` to `orWhere()`?

Comment: all the `and`s  are a sub-query so its ok to be `and ads.id in (select ...)`, but it cant be `and attribute_id = 1 and attribute_id = 2` !

Comment: Yeah I realized that. Did the edit help?

Comment: actually it's changed to `OR` which will almost always be true :") ....

Comment: You really need to make your requirements more clear. Set up a fiddle and edit your question to include a link to it, and your desired output for a given set of search terms.

Comment: I added fiddle url, its really simple set of data but it provides the idea

Answer (score 1):

The Entity-Attribute-Value schema pattern is notoriously verbose and inefficient.  But it is flexible.

It *may* help to add this "composite" index (that is also "covering") to the table `ad_attributes`:

```
INDEX(attribute_id, value, ad_attributes)
```